# Ler input do usuário sem usar a função prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js

A única maneira de atribuir valor a uma variável pelo usuário no JavaScript é utilizando a função `prompt` ou existe alguma outra?

Porque no Python, por exemplo, podemos fazer assim:

```
numero = int(input("Informe um número: "))
```

Pergunto isso, pois estou rodando meus códigos JavaScript no terminal do node.js e lá não aceita a função `prompt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `Node.js` você pode usar o módulo [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/readline.html):

```
const readline = require('readline');

const input = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

input.question('Informe um número: ', (resposta) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Número informado: ${resposta}`);
  input.close();
});
```

---

Caso queira utilizar `async/await` você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const input = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

const perguntar = (pergunta) =>  new Promise(resolver => input.question(pergunta, (resposta) => resolver(resposta)));

const executar = async () => {
  console.time('Execução');

  try {
    const resposta = await perguntar('Informe um número: ');
    console.log(`Número informado: ${resposta}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  // Totaliza o tempo de execução
  console.timeEnd('Execução');
}

executar();
```

> [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/readline.html)
>
> The readline module provides an interface for reading data from a Readable stream (such as process.stdin) one line at a time.

Em tradução livre:

> O módulo readline provê uma interface para leitura de dados de um stream Readable (como o process.stdin) uma linha por vez.

Comment: O responsável pelo downvote pode explanar o motivo que torna minha resposta errada (apesar da aceitação da pessoa que perguntou) pelo qual minha resposta estaria errada?